# Stochastic solution for geodesic equation under normal gaussian noise

Tags: geometry

This is more as a curiosity question rather than a doubt: We know the geodesic equation on a manifold endowed with metric $g_{ij}$ is given by null covariant derivative $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma} = 0$, which gives us equality $\ddot{\gamma}^k + \Gamma^k_{ij} \dot{\gamma}^i \dot{\gamma}^j = 0$.

My question: is there any development such that covariant derivative $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}$ is given by some disturbance function $\delta$, which may be an stochasstic normal variable $z(s) \in \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$. Thanks in advance! :)